# Bootstrap modals blank with CDN-delivered js & css resources

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty stuck on this problem that I'm having getting Bootstrap modals to pop up. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xaU5d/

```
    <div class="container">  
        <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>  
        <div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">  
            <div class="modal-header">  
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
                <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>  
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-body">  
                <h4>Text in a modal</h4>  
                <p>You can add some text here.</p>                
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-footer">  
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>  
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
    <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
Launch demo modal</a></p>  
    </div>
```

And pulling the css from:

```
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.css
```

Essentially, the when the button is pressed, the modal tries to load (the style changes to the body happen which causes it to dim), but the  tags containing the modal content never get rendered.

I believe this is a CSS problem at heart. When you remove the css and rerun, the styles go away, of course, but clicking on the anchor actually causes the change to happen.

I have to assume it's something that I'm doing, so could anyone look at the jsfiddle example and let me know where my error is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer, but adding `modal-content` to your `div id="example`` allows the modal to run, but not on the correct layer.

Bootstrap 3 changed how they load modals a bit:

> Modal markup has changed significantly. The .modal-header, .modal-body, and .modal-footer sections are now wrapped in .modal-content and .modal-dialog for better mobile styling and behavior.

Comment: Got it. I think I just got too caught up in older tutorials, rather than going to the source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals